# static inline void function has warning "control reaches end of non-void function"

Tags: c, warnings, void, gcc-warning

I currently have the following function in C:

```
static inline void *cmyk_to_rgb(int *dest, int *cmyk)
{
    double c = cmyk[0] / 100.0;
    double m = cmyk[1] / 100.0;
    double y = cmyk[2] / 100.0;
    double k = cmyk[3] / 100.0;

    c = c * (1 - k) + k;
    m = m * (1 - k) + k;
    y = y * (1 - k) + k;

    dest[0] = ROUND((1 - c) * 255);
    dest[1] = ROUND((1 - m) * 255);
    dest[2] = ROUND((1 - y) * 255);
}
```

When compiling, I am warned that

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

I've tried adding an explicit `return` at the end of the function body and that results in an outright error. What is the proper way to resolve this warning? Any solutions I've found online involve adding a return statement where the function is supposed to return some value (`int` etc.), but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void *` is not `void`

Change your first line to

```
static inline void cmyk_to_rgb(int *dest, int *cmyk)
```

`void *` is some pointer that isn't specified as being a particular type. Not returning a value from a function specified as returning `int *` would give you a similar error.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks, that fixed it. I originally wrote it as returning `int *` but evidently did not clean things up very well.